# Kafka API CommitFailed Exception semantic

Tags: apache-kafka

I wonder what happen when you get a commit failed exception because some partition were revoked, and you are committing a batch of offsets of revoked partition and partition your own. Does everything get rejected, or those you own go trough, and the exception only concerns those offsets you do not own anymore.